# Show Toast in a Widget from a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-appwidget

I've to develop a widget (AppWidget) that contains a button.
When the button is pressed an http request is done and, if the request is successful, the widget notify the fact through a Toast.
Since the http request can lock the UI, I run it in a thread.
All it's working fine (I can see "*All right*" in my logat), except for the Toast notification.
What am I doing wrong?

**In the AppWidgetProvider subclass:**

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){
        super.onReceive(c, intent);
        if(intent.getAction().equals(CLICK_ACTION)){
            performRequest(c);
        }
    }
```

(I think onUpdate method is not necessary for the question)

```
private void performRequest(final Context c){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                if(Http.get(URL).contains(SUCCESS)){
                Toast.makeText(c, "All right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                      
                Log.i("Widget","All right");        
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}}).start();
}
```

I think that the problem is the `Context` argument of `performRequest`, but if I remove the `final` keyword, I have errors.

Thanks in advice.

**[EDIT]**

I "solved" the problem in this way:

-I declare `Toast t` as a global variable;

-Inside the onReceive method I initialize it with `Toast.makeText(Context,String,int)`

-When I need to show it, I simply call `t.show()`

I hope that there are better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the http request can lock the UI, I run it in a thread. All it's working fine (I can view "All right" in my logat), except for the Toast notification. What am I doing wrong?

The problem is you cannot alter the UI from another Thread.  You must pass this message back to the main Thread in order to display your Toast.

---

> How can I do it?

There are a lot of different ways to do this, try saving the Context in `onReceive()` as a field variable:

```
Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){
    super.onReceive(c, intent);
    context = c;
    ...
```

Next create a simple method in your Activity:

```
public void httpGetSucceeded() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "All right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                      
    Log.i("Widget","All right");        
}
```

Now call this inside your Runnable:

```
try {
    if(Http.get(URL).contains(SUCCESS)){
         httpGetSucceeded();
    }
} //etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I do it?

Comment: My Runnable is in the AppWidgetProvider subclass, so it doesn't see an activity's method (you mean the main activity, right?)

Comment: Ok, then put `httpGetSucceeded()` in your AppWidgetProvider intead. (Sorry, I should've notice that.)

Comment: Toast.makeText needs a Context as the firs argument. If I use `this` it points to an `AppWidgetProvider` instance.

Comment: Ok, you were using `c` before what happens when you use that instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25185/discussion-between-supergiox-and-sam)

Comment: You cant use this because this is not valid for passing a thread to the toast message. Contextually speaking you need to pay attention where you are using the keyword this.

Comment: @supergiox Sorry, I got pulled away. Have you solved this yet? Either way I updated my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, why don't you have a handler that dispatches a message after the thread completes its task. When you receive that message in your broadcast receiver just consume the message and display the toast by using the post runnable method from the Handler object.

Because the handler will belong to your broadcast receiver, you should be running on the UI thread when you call the post for the runnable.

### Ref

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it.

Comment: I tried it. I create an Handler inside `onReceive()` and I send the notification Message from the thread. But anyway I had to make the Toast from the handler and to do this operation I need a Context, and this is the same problem of the question.

Comment: You need to have the context either passed in the message's obj variable OR have the context object be static in your broadcast receiver.

Comment: How can I pass a Context through a message? (Context isn't Parcelable).

Comment: technically you can its an object that you can pass between the.. two but it would probably be preferred to use a static Context object that you maintain in the receiver and after its been used free it up by setting it to Null.

Comment: The static way is the first one I've tried. I declared the Context as a static attribute of the class and I assign it a value inside onReveice() (because there I've a Context reference). I've no errors/warning (neither in logat), but the Toast is not shown.

Comment: Update your post with what you have now. Also keep in mind that the displaying of the toast must come from the handler code being invoked after the task is done.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to call

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // launch toast here
  }
});
```

Or, given a specific widget:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // launch toast here
  }
});
```

Comment: context does not have runOnUiThread also, he doesn't necessarily has a view at any given point during this process. Since its **after** the thread has completed. -1

Comment: Old habits die hard; I generally name my Activity reference "ctx".  I've edited my response accordingly.

Comment: Hehe, hes not in an activity either, so your response about activity is invalid. Hes asking within the widget context not an activity or view :)

Comment: Wrong, you don't need an activity to show a toast... last I checked. It can also come from a broadcast receiver. BUT it must come from the same thread the broadcast receiver is running on.